# Odoo 10 - Get current user for use in mail template

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

A common definition for email template is to use:

```
${(object.user_id.email and '%s <%s>' % (object.user_id.name, object.user_id.email) or '')|safe}
```

I am trying to use the email from the logged user, not from the object's user:

```
${(self.env.user.email and '%s <%s>' % (self.env.user.name, self.env.user.email) or '')|safe}
```

What is wrong in self.env.user.email?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try as following :

```
${(user.email and '%s <%s>' % (user.name, user.email) or '')|safe}
```